# Have Spock fail a data-driven feature if an iteration fails

Tags: spock

Is there a way to do the equivalent of `@Stepwise`'s failure behavior for a single feature? We have some integration tests that are set up such that `setupSpec()` kicks off a Kafka process, and then the actual test checks that each step happened. If step 3 failed, there's no reason to bother checking subsequent steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this, but assuming you are using a recent 2.x Spock version and not 1.3 or so, a relatively simple annotation-driven Spock extension can do the trick for you.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q71414311

import org.spockframework.runtime.extension.ExtensionAnnotation

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType
import java.lang.annotation.Retention
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy
import java.lang.annotation.Target

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@ExtensionAnnotation(StepwiseIterationsExtension)
@interface StepwiseIterations {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q71414311

import org.spockframework.runtime.extension.IAnnotationDrivenExtension
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.FeatureInfo
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.parallel.ExecutionMode

class StepwiseIterationsExtension implements IAnnotationDrivenExtension<StepwiseIterations> {
  @Override
  void visitFeatureAnnotation(StepwiseIterations annotation, FeatureInfo feature) {
    // Disable parallel iteration execution for @StepwiseIterations feature,
    // similarly to how @Stepwise disables it for the whole specification
    feature.setExecutionMode(ExecutionMode.SAME_THREAD)

    // If an error occurs in this feature, skip remaining iterations
    feature.getFeatureMethod().addInterceptor({ invocation ->
      try {
        invocation.proceed()
      }
      catch (Throwable t) {
        invocation.getFeature().skip("skipping subsequent iterations after failure")
        throw t
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Add this to your code base, annotate your iterated test with `@StepwiseIterations` and run it. I think the result is exactly what you are looking for.

In Spock 1.3, an similar, but more complex extension would also be possible.

*I also want to express my special thanks to [Leonard Brünings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2145769/leonard-br%c3%bcnings), Spock maintainer and boundless source of knowledge. I had a more complex version of this extension in place, but after discussing with him, it evolved into this  tiny, elegant solution we are seeing here.*

---

FYI, there is a pre-existing [Spock issue #1008](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/1008) requesting this feature. I created [pull request #1442](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/pull/1442) which adds this capability to `@Stepwise`. So hopefully in the future we do not need an extra annotation and extra extension anymore.

Comment: **Update:** I synchronised the sample code with Spock #1442, making it a bit neater.

Comment: That works like a charm. Thank you! And with a pull request and everything?!

Comment: Well, it was an interesting question... 

Comment: Good news: [Spock PR #1442](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/pull/1442) was merged into the main branch, i.e. it will be part of the next Spock release, which will probably have a version like 2.2-M2, and then also in 2.2 proper.